# Javascript + AngularJS call scope function from another scope function nested function as parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have angular controller with 2 functions **delete** and **upload**.
 Inside ***upload***, i call an object's function which takes in its parameters from another function. For the success callback,
i want to call the scope.delete from this success method
example code inside the controller

```
$scope.delete = function () {
    somecode
}

$scope.upload = function(){
    var scope = $scope;
    object.select(var1, function() { 
        //some code
        //here i want to call scope.delete(): but i get scope is not defined

    });
}
```

Comment: Why call `$scope.delete` ? Why not make a function that is called by `$scope.delete` which you then also can call from `$.scope.upload` as needed.

Comment: Please add fiddle. Are you getting an error while calling $scope.delete()?

Comment: Mohan Ram 
I call scope.delete and i get scope is not defined

Comment: @AmgadAli are you calling function like `scope.delete()` or `$scope.delete()` ?.. You should call like `$scope.delete`

Comment: I defined a new variable called scope = $scope then i can call it from the upload function but not from the success function

Comment: What is 'object.select' ? I think this may cause the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please use closure to make scope variable private, so you can use inside object method which you want to call
[Closure](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/)